# Principle of physical independence of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

> *x* part of the motion occurs exactly as it would if the *y* part did not occur at all. Similarly, the *y* part of the motion occurs exactly as it would if the *x* part of the motion did not exist. in other words, x and y motion is independent of each other

Does this concept mean that the *x* part of motion never influences the *y* part? Because, as written if each motion happens as if other didn't exist, then it simply means it will act as it would have if other was absent, but logically speaking, say an airplane is flying and is bound to reach a point *b* in 5 seconds, suddenly gravity increases by 100%, and the plane diverts in the influence of gravity, and hence never reaches point B, so this shows that vertical component has influenced the horizontal motion which the airplane would have achieved independently.

Comment: Bizarre quote. Maybe it is in the context of projectile motion? $x$ and $y$ motion are independent of one another if the equations of motion are decoupled. However, it is definitely possible to have situations where you have equations of motion that are coupled.

Comment: In your example, the plane will still reach x=b in 5 seconds even with double gravity, if its initial altitude is high enough and does not hit the ground first.

Comment: @Evan Got any simple examples for the coupled motion case?

Answer (score 1):

If such a situation happens and plane is highly diverted towards ground it will still cover the horizontal distance in same time.
Now suppose the plane touched the ground and did not reach other point we can say the horizontal frictional force affected its horizontal motion not the vertical force which increased many times. So still the two motions are independent of each other and of course connected by time.

Answer (score 0):

This statement of independence is only true with acceleration only in one direction and without friction. so usually you use it for oblique throw with  heavy objects and comparatively small starting v. for the real throw with air friction it is wrong. But your example is not good, if without friction you could increase g, the two motions would be independent, motion in x direction still $s=v_x*t$ and motion in y direction just with greater g, so in the same time motion in x stays the same and is not influenced bei y, so you end up farther down in given time.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a statement that arises from the fact that *mass is a scalar* quantity, and not a tensor like mass moment of inertia.

A particle feels equally the same mass regardless of direction of motion, and the same goes for rigid bodies.

As a result when you look at momentum and the *x* and *y* components you have

$$ \begin{aligned}
  p_x & = m v_x \\
  p_y & = m v_y 
\end {aligned} $$

as long as the two components are orthogonal to each other.

Newton's second law takes the above into the familiar form

$$ \begin{aligned}
  F_x & = m a_x \\
  F_y & = m a_y 
\end {aligned} $$

which means things the happen along the *x* axis, do not affect the motion along the *y* axis.

---

Now suppose there was a preferred direction which decoupled the equations of motion, and it was at an angle $\theta$ from the current coordinate system. Then the equation of motion would be

$$ \begin{aligned}
  F_x & =\left( (m_2 + (m_1-m_2) \cos^2 \theta) a_x + ((m_1-m_2) \cos \theta \sin \theta) a_y \right) \\
  F_y & =\left( ((m_1-m_2) \cos \theta \sin \theta) a_x + (m_1 - (m_1-m_2) \cos^2 \theta) a_y \right) 
\end {aligned} $$

where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses felt through the preferred direction and its perpendicular.

and in that case forces along the *x* direction affect the motion of both *x* and *y* directions and vise versa.

That is not what we observe at all. As far as we can tell from the tiny scales to planetary scales ***mass is a scalar quantity*** and $m_1 \equiv m_2$ in all cases.

Comment: No, $F_x$ can still depend on $y$, $v_y$ or even $a_y$ for example. So, it is not necessary that the equations of motion for $x,y$ are always decoupled.

Comment: @DvijD.C. - Net force is decoupled by nature of $\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$, This is what I am explaining in the answer. You cannot have the _x_-axis component of net force depend on the _y_-axis acceleration. Care to give me a counter example? (acceleration as measured at the center of mass).